# Equivalent metrics on compact metric space

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a compact metric space with two metrics $d,d'$ inducing the same topology on $X$.

Show or find a counterexample to:

There exists a sequence $(\delta_n)_n$ such that $\delta_n\rightarrow 0$ such that for every $\epsilon>0$ if $d(x,y)<\epsilon$ then $d'(x,y)<\delta_n$ for any large $n \in \Bbb N$.

Thoughts:

(1). Since $d,d'$ induce the same topology, it follows that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $d(x,y)<\delta$ then $d'(x,y)<\epsilon$ .

(2). Assume there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for each $n$, there exists $x_n,y_n\in X$ such that if $d(x_n,y_n)<\epsilon$ then $d'(x_n,y_n)\geq \frac{1}{n}$. Since $X$ is compact, assume WLOG $x_n\rightarrow x$ and $y_n\rightarrow y$. Then, $d(x,y)\leq \epsilon$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "$d'(x,y) < \delta_n$"? Do you mean **there exists an $n$** such that this inequality holds?

Comment: @Ben Grossman yup

Comment: Please edit your question to make it understandable without my comment. Also, in the question as it is currently written, it is implicit that the sequence might depend on the choice of $\epsilon$, which doesn't make much sense. It sounds like there's supposed to be a sequence such that this holds for *all epsilon*. Again, please edit your question so that all this is clear.

Comment: @BenGrossmann done

Comment: If the metric $d$ and $d'$ induce the same topology, then the identity function $I:(X,d)\rightarrow(X,d')$ and its inverse (whihc is also the identity function) $I^{-1}:(X,d')\rightarrow(X,d)$ are continuous.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Sorry. Yes I know that, but where does the $\delta_n$ come from?

Comment: @MathematicallyInterested: now you can make the standard $\varepsilon-\delta$ argument between continuous functions. End of story.